# Need ‘typename’ before ‘std::result_of<_Signature>::type’ because ‘std::result_of<_Signature>’ is a dependent scope

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, result-of

I can't any good solution. I have piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <queue>
#include <type_traits>
#include "threadsafe_queue.hpp"

using namespace std;

template<int ...>
struct seq { };

template<int N, int ...S>
struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> { };

template<int ...S>
struct gens<0, S...> {
    typedef seq<S...> type;
};

class JoinThreads {
    vector<std::thread>& m_threads;
public:
    explicit JoinThreads(vector<std::thread>& threads): m_threads(threads) {}

    ~JoinThreads() {
        for (unsigned long a = 0; a < this-> m_threads.size(); a++) {
            if (this->m_threads[a].joinable()) {
                this->m_threads[a].join();
            }
        }
    }

};

template<typename T>
class Callable {
    T m_proc;
public:
    Callable() {}

    Callable(T proc): m_proc(proc) {
        //
    }

    template<typename ... V>
    typename std::result_of<T>::type Call(V ... args) {
        return this-> m_proc(args ...);
    }

};

template<typename ResultType>
class TaskResult {
    ResultType m_result;
public:
    TaskResult(ResultType result) {}
    ResultType result() const {
        return this-> m_result;
    }
};

template<typename CallableType, typename ... ArgType>
class Task {
    Callable<CallableType> m_callable;
    std::tuple<ArgType...> m_args;
    void (*m_callback)(TaskResult<CallableType>);

    template<int ...S>
    typename std::result_of<CallableType>::type invokeCallable(seq<S...>) {
        return this-> m_callable.Call(std::get<S>(this-> m_args) ...);
    }
protected:
    typedef typename std::result_of<CallableType>::type callableType;
public:
    Task() {}

    Task(Callable<CallableType> callable, ArgType ... args, TaskResult<CallableType> callback): m_callable(callable), m_callback(callback) {
        this-> m_args = std::make_tuple(args ...);
    }

    void Execute() {
        typename std::result_of<CallableType>::type result = this-> invokeCallable(typename gens<sizeof...(ArgType)>::type());
        void (*callback)(TaskResult<CallableType>) = reinterpret_cast<void (*)(TaskResult<CallableType>) >(this-> m_callback);

        if (0 < (size_t)callback) {
            this-> m_callback(TaskResult<CallableType>(result));
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Dequeue {
    threadsafe_queue<T> m_tasks;
    std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
    std::atomic_bool m_done;
    JoinThreads m_joiner;
    void Process() {
        typename threadsafe_queue<T>::m_size_type size = 0;
        while (!m_done) {
            T task;
            if (this-> m_tasks.try_pop(task)) {
                task.Execute();
            } else {
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
        }
    }
public:
    Dequeue(unsigned threads = 0): m_done(false), m_joiner(m_threads) {
        unsigned const threadCount = threads > 0 ? threads : std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

        cout << "Threads count: " << threadCount << endl;

        try {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i) {
                this-> m_threads.push_back(std::thread(&Dequeue::Process, this));
            }
        } catch (...) {
            this-> m_done = true;
            throw;
        }
    }

    ~Dequeue() {
        this-> m_done = true;
    }

    template<typename CallableType, typename CallbackType, typename ... ArgType>
    void Subscribe(CallableType callable, CallbackType callback, ArgType ... args) {
        this-> m_tasks.push(Task<CallableType, CallbackType, ArgType...> (callable, args ..., callback));
    }

    void Subscribe(T task) {
        this-> m_tasks.push(task);
    }

};


template<typename CallableType, typename CallbackType, typename ... ArgType>
Task<CallableType, CallbackType, ArgType ...> SubscribeTask(CallableType callable, CallbackType callback, ArgType ... args) {
    return Task<CallableType, CallbackType, ArgType...> (callable, args ..., callback);
}

int foo(int a, int b) {
    int N = 1024, tab[N], z = 0;
    //Some long task
    return tab[0];
}

void callback(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)> res) {
    cout << "Callback" << endl;
}

/*
 * Callback jednak warto zrobić z parametrem jako obiekt jakiegoś zdarzenia i
 * nie wymuszać konieczności podania parametru szablonu.
 */

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    Dequeue<Task<int (*)(int, int), int, int> > dequeue(4);
    cout << "Pushing tasks..." << endl;
    dequeue.Subscribe(foo, callback, 2156, 55);
    for (int a = 0; a < 1024; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 1024; b++) {
            dequeue.Subscribe(foo, callback, a, b);
        }
    }

    cout << "Processing..." << endl;
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: here you are header

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue {
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<T> data_queue;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
public:
    typedef
    typename
    std::queue<T>::size_type m_size_type;
    threadsafe_queue() {
    }
    threadsafe_queue(threadsafe_queue const& other) {
        std::lock_guard < std::mutex > lk(other.mut);
        data_queue = other.data_queue;
    }

    void push(T new_value) {
        std::lock_guard < std::mutex > lk(mut);
        data_queue.push(new_value);
        data_cond.notify_one();
    }

    void wait_and_pop(T& value) {
        std::unique_lock < std::mutex > lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk, [this] {return !data_queue.empty();});
        value = data_queue.front();
        data_queue.pop();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> wait_and_pop() {
        std::unique_lock < std::mutex > lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk, [this] {return !data_queue.empty();});
        std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared < T > (data_queue.front()));
        data_queue.pop();
        return res;
    }

    bool try_pop(T& value) {
        std::lock_guard < std::mutex > lk(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty())
            return false;
        value = data_queue.front();
        data_queue.pop();
        return true;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop() {
        std::lock_guard < std::mutex > lk(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty())
            return std::shared_ptr<T>();
        std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared < T > (data_queue.front()));
        data_queue.pop();
        return res;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        std::lock_guard < std::mutex > lk(mut);
        return data_queue.empty();
    }

    m_size_type size() const {
        std::lock_guard < std::mutex > lk(mut);
        return data_queue.size();
    }
};
```

I have error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Callable<int (*)(int, int)>’:
main.cpp:69:25:   required from ‘class Task<int (*)(int, int), void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>), int, int>’
main.cpp:135:3:   required from ‘void Dequeue<T>::Subscribe(CallableType, CallbackType, ArgType ...) [with CallableType = int (*)(int, int); CallbackType = void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>); ArgType = {int, int}; T = Task<int (*)(int, int), int, int>]’
main.cpp:175:43:   required from here
main.cpp:51:35: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::result_of<int (*)(int, int)>’
  typename std::result_of<T>::type Call(V ... args) {
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/type_traits:2060:11: error: declaration of ‘class std::result_of<int (*)(int, int)>’
     class result_of;
           ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Task<int (*)(int, int), void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>), int, int>’:
main.cpp:135:3:   required from ‘void Dequeue<T>::Subscribe(CallableType, CallbackType, ArgType ...) [with CallableType = int (*)(int, int); CallbackType = void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>); ArgType = {int, int}; T = Task<int (*)(int, int), int, int>]’
main.cpp:175:43:   required from here
main.cpp:74:46: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::result_of<int (*)(int, int)>’
  typename std::result_of<CallableType>::type invokeCallable(seq<S...>) {
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/type_traits:2060:11: error: declaration of ‘class std::result_of<int (*)(int, int)>’
     class result_of;
           ^
main.cpp:78:54: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::result_of<int (*)(int, int)>’
  typedef typename std::result_of<CallableType>::type callableType;
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/type_traits:2060:11: error: declaration of ‘class std::result_of<int (*)(int, int)>’
     class result_of;
           ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Dequeue<T>::Subscribe(CallableType, CallbackType, ArgType ...) [with CallableType = int (*)(int, int); CallbackType = void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>); ArgType = {int, int}; T = Task<int (*)(int, int), int, int>]’:
main.cpp:175:43:   required from here
main.cpp:135:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘Task<int (*)(int, int), void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>), int, int>::Task(int (*&)(int, int), int&, int&, void (*&)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>))’
   this-> m_tasks.push(Task<CallableType, CallbackType, ArgType...> (callable, args ..., callback));
   ^
main.cpp:135:3: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:82:2: note: Task<CallableType, ArgType>::Task(Callable<CallableType>, ArgType ..., TaskResult<CallableType>) [with CallableType = int (*)(int, int); ArgType = {void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>), int, int}]
  Task(Callable<CallableType> callable, ArgType ... args, TaskResult<CallableType> callback): m_callable(callable), m_callback(callback) {
  ^
main.cpp:82:2: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 4 provided
main.cpp:80:2: note: Task<CallableType, ArgType>::Task() [with CallableType = int (*)(int, int); ArgType = {void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>), int, int}]
  Task() {}
  ^
main.cpp:80:2: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
main.cpp:68:7: note: constexpr Task<int (*)(int, int), void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>), int, int>::Task(const Task<int (*)(int, int), void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>), int, int>&)
 class Task {
       ^
main.cpp:68:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
main.cpp:68:7: note: constexpr Task<int (*)(int, int), void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>), int, int>::Task(Task<int (*)(int, int), void (*)(TaskResult<int (*)(int, int)>), int, int>&&)
main.cpp:68:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Task<int (*)(int, int), int, int>’:
main.cpp:105:6:   required from ‘void Dequeue<T>::Process() [with T = Task<int (*)(int, int), int, int>]’
main.cpp:121:44:   required from ‘Dequeue<T>::Dequeue(unsigned int) [with T = Task<int (*)(int, int), int, int>]’
main.cpp:173:55:   required from here
main.cpp:74:46: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::result_of<int (*)(int, int)>’
  typename std::result_of<CallableType>::type invokeCallable(seq<S...>) {
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/type_traits:2060:11: error: declaration of ‘class std::result_of<int (*)(int, int)>’
     class result_of;
           ^
main.cpp:78:54: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::result_of<int (*)(int, int)>’
  typedef typename std::result_of<CallableType>::type callableType;
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/type_traits:2060:11: error: declaration of ‘class std::result_of<int (*)(int, int)>’
     class result_of;
```

I tried add typename before use of result_of but it caused other error: "ivalid use of incomplite type...".

I want to have something like you see in main function. I want to add new tasks to something like thread pool. Template arguments should be given as little as it is possible. Perfect solution is deducing at all :-) .

Comment: The error is not reproducible because of a missed header. You should rather create a minimal example.

Comment: You are using `result_of` wrong.

Comment: @T.C.: Yeah, "If you have error, fix it and it will be fixed!". It doesn't work at all. I know that I am using it wrong, compiler told me. I just try find out how use it right or just use something else.

Answer (score 2):

In `result_of<>` you have to pass not only the type of the function (`T`, in your case) but also the types of the arguments.

So, if I understand your intentions, your `Callable` class should also receive a variadic list of argument (say `ArgsT`) and use they (`std::result_of<T(ArgsT...)>::type`).

In other words, I suppose that your `Callable` class should be

```
template<typename T, typename ... ArgsT>
class Callable {
    T m_proc;
public:
    Callable() {}

    Callable(T proc): m_proc(proc) {
        //
    }

    template<typename ... V>
    typename std::result_of<T(ArgsT...)>::type Call(V ... args) {
        return this-> m_proc(args ...);
    }
};
```

and, by example in `Task`, should be called as

```
Callable<CallableType, ArgType...> m_callable;
```

Same solution with other uses of `result_of<>`: pass to the type function the arg types

```
typename std::result_of<CallableType(ArgType...)>::type
```

Comment: It seems like I need to verify project assumptions, not all can be reconciled. However, thanks for good clue.